# How to reference Nuget binaries in Wix Bundle PayLoad?

Tags: c#, wix, nuget, bundle, bootstrapper

I am publishing my Bootstrapper.dll on a local nuget server during its build, and this is working fine. But to use it in my Bundle projects (wixproj), I can't find any direct method to reference this in PayLoad. 
**As a workaround** I have created a dummy C# project, adding the nuget reference, Copy Local=True and then referencing this dummy C# project's TargetDir\Bootstrapper.dll in Bundle PayLoad.

**Question:** Is there any way to avoid using dummy C# project and using nuget referenced binaries in Bundle's PayLoad directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can install the NuGet package in your Wix Bootstrapper project. Create a install.ps1 to update Payloads in your Bundle.wxs. At the end of install.ps1 save the project.

```
$project.Save($project.FullName)
```

Don't forget to undo the changes made in install.ps1 in uninstall.ps1 to keep everything nice an clean.
The above described procedure will save you from creating C# dummy project.